# Specifying Absolute Path using VBScript

Tags: linux, vbscript, wine

I have VBScript that is taking output from a Word file and generating a text file with that output. The current code shown below assumes that I want to create the file in my desktop.

The issue that I am having is that I plan to use wine on Linux to execute my VBScript. Is there anyway that i can modify this code to specify the Linux path to output this file?

```
fileName = "\out.txt"
strPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & fileName

Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oFile As Object 
Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(strPath)
```

Comment: The code you posted is not VBScript. Is it VBA?

Comment: The extension type is .vb

Comment: In order to convert it to VBScript, you should remove all the type definitions (`As Object`) and save with the `.vbs` extension. Also, if you are running under WINE, then presumably you can pass in the Linux path to `CreateTextFile`.